# RestKit add entity error

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, restkit

Launch the application
Spend initialize the Server Manager
In its response trying to add tags
in paragraph 3 call mappingForEntityForName: inManagedObjectStore
error

`[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName: inManagedObjectStore]` flies Unable to find an Entity with the name 'User' in the managed object model
The essence of the User database with class KGUser there .

Here Log

```
2015-07-27 13:45:01.842 GeekBrains[57319:3205602] /Users/tahyku/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F5E648-DA94-48EA-931A-A741CE7A2FA7/data/Containers/Data/Application/F9825B68-4013-4736-9624-45D5783E45E3/Documents/KGStudio.GeekBrains
2015-07-27 13:45:04.976 GeekBrains[57319:3205602] {
}
2015-07-27 13:45:06.021 GeekBrains[57319:3205602] *** Assertion failure in +[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:inManagedObjectStore:], /Users/tahyku/Desktop/geekbrains-ios/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKEntityMapping.m:158
2015-07-27 13:45:06.068 GeekBrains[57319:3205602] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to find an Entity with the name 'User' in the managed object model'
```

Please, help!

Comment: Show the setup code, did you create the store and contexts? Does the model have a user entity?

Comment: Is this a machine translation?

Comment: Hello! Bug was fixed by myself.
I create project without coreData, and then create dataBase.